# iOS AlertView trigger which button has been pressed

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am trying to see what option the client has pushed on the alert view button, though the logging doesn't appear to be working

```
-(IBAction)flattenBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView* flatView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Flatten Image"
                                                        message:@"Are you sure you want to flatten your image?" delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No",nil];
    [flatView show];
    [flatView release];
}


- (void)flatView:(UIAlertView *)flatView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using like this :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
       //your code if YES pressed;
    }
    else
    {
      //your code if NO pressed;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir that user put wrong delegate method of alertview that not issue with name. Method not going to be called.

Comment: Ohh. Missed on that in a hurry. You need to use `alertView` instead of `flatView` Paul. That will nail this.